# Trying to get curl to work in c++ linux and GDB

Tags: c++, linux, curl, gdb, raspberry-pi

I have tried everything I can find online, but I keep getting the error "undefined reference to 'curl_global_init'"

A couple places recommended putting -lcurl in the command line, but this is being done through Visual GDB/Visual Studio and I am not sure exactly where to put it. I tried a dozen places with no luck.

```
#include "curl/curl.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
CURL *curl;
   CURLcode res;

   curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );
}
```

I can right click on curl_global_init and go to the definition without a problem.
Also, I can run curl fine from the command line on my raspberry pi.

Thanx in advance, been stuck on this for far too long.

Comment: Compile your program with `gcc -Wall -g testcurl.c -lcurl -o testcurl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a linking issue.

When you right click and go to the definition or declaration of functions or variables this is based on the IDE not the compiler. The compiler must be linked very strictly to cURL library either in the command line as compiler flags or in your IDE settings (that creates the command line for you).

While I am using MVS10 on Win7 I had similar problems initially. Many of the guides floating around for how to correctly link curl to your IDE are VERY specific and in many cases will not work for your situation.
I strongly recommend you compile your own library from the latest curl file whether its static or dynamic. Dynamic is the easiest to get to compile originally (I found) to do a basic compile before you have to link your DLL after. The program will not run without the DLL's linked though may still compile.
Good Luck!